# Why is WSL not ignoring blank lines in bash script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently switched from using Ubuntu on dual-boot to using it on WSL. I had a bash script that worked perfectly fine on Ubuntu, which I then cloned from a GitHub repo to windows. When I attempt to run the script in WSL I get the following error:

```
batch.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

How do I clone the repo using the windows installation of git such that newline character treatment is compatible with WSL?

---

**Edit:** This question was significantly rephrased to more accurately describe the problem.

Comment: In the Unix/Linux world If there is a carriage return then the line is not blank.

Comment: How did you copy the file from Ubuntu?

Comment: @gronostaj cloned a git repo containing it.

Comment: @MShaikG This isn't a WSL, Windows, or Ubuntu issue... it's a `git` issue. There are details in [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1551663/529800) that are crucial to this question, and with those details, the way this question is currently worded is no longer factually accurate.

Comment: @MShaikG Thank you for adding the _Edit_ line, however this question needs a re-write to make it factually accurate and applicable.  The title alone is not relevant to the issue, as this is not an OS issue, but a `git` issue experienced, as @gronastaj laid out in their answer, due to options chosen during `git` installation on Windows.  It would be to the benefit of factual accuracy to swap out the bulk of the wording in this question with wording similar to that in your answer to make it factually accurate and applicable to what's been experienced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) (which also has lots more info about this type of problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not WSL's fault.

When you're installing git on Windows, the installer asks you which newline treatment you'd like it to use. You must have selected "Checkout as CRLF, commit as LF". Thus git inserts extra `\r` characters in your text files which were not present on Linux (if they were present you'd be getting the same errors).

You can change this settings in `.gitconfig` file in your home directory (`C:\Users\YourUsername`). It's called `core.autocrlf`. Possible values are:

- `true` (your current setting)
- `input` (checkout as-is, commit LF)
- `false` (checkout and commit as-is).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my particular issue. The bash script was copied to Windows from a cloned GitHub repo, however I cloned the repo from cmd. The issue was resolved when I cloned the repo from WSL. Presumably the cause of the problem has to do with the difference in how the 2 operating systems handle/interpret `\n` and `\r` characters.

There's definitely a more technical explanation that can be given than mine.

Comment: This isn't a WSL, Windows, or Ubuntu issue... it's a `git` issue.  There are details in this answer that are crucial to your question, and with these details, the way your question is currently worded is no longer factually accurate.